# Rails Error comparing object with parameter inside view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I have my index.html like this:

```
<% @alumno_inscriptos.each do |alumno_inscripto| %>
  <tr>
    <% if (alumno_inscripto.clase_id) == (params[:id])  %>
        <td><%= alumno_inscripto.clase_id %><td>
        <td><%= params[:id] %><td>
        <td><%= buscarNombre(alumno_inscripto.alumno_id).name %>  <%= buscarNombre(alumno_inscripto.alumno_id).lastname %>  </td>
        <td>  <%= alumno_inscripto.presencia %></td>
        <td>  <%= alumno_inscripto.pago %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', alumno_inscripto, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    <% else %>
        <td><%= "no va. solo para testear" %><td>
        <td><%= alumno_inscripto.clase_id %><td>
        <td><%= params[:id] %><td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

[image]

The problem is that inside the 'if', if the 2 parameters are the same, it always goes to the else part. I leave you an image of what it print. As you can see in the last row the values are the same. Do you have a solution for this?

Thank you!

Comment: what is your params[:id]? . See if it has value by simply printing in it your index.html.erb

Comment: i printed it. its the last sentence. above the end. both print '2'

Comment: `clase_id` i suppose is always integer? whereas `params[:id]` should be string. Cast them to the same class and try again

Comment: that was the solution. i add params[:id].to_i . thanks